# HTML/CSS Pricing layout

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

im a designer, and im trying to create a pricing table with a custom pricing layout. i have tried to do it with html and css, but i cant find a way to put the "12x" bellow the "R$", and both beside the price "219".

that's the pricing layout that im trying to create
[pricing layout that i need to create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEzD1.png)

i have found ways to use the "R$" beside the price, but the "12x" wont show bellow "R$". only in the line under the price.

Comment: Have you tried setting the containers position to relative using: position:relative; then setting the x12 node to position absolute?

Comment: show us some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by divs and styling them by display: flex

```css
.wrapp, .priceWrapp, .firstBlock, .secondBlock{
  display: flex;
}

.wrapp{
  width: 340px;
}

.wrapp, .firstBlock{
  flex-direction: column;
}

.firstBlock, .restPrice{
  font-size: 2.5em;
}
.firstBlock{
  flex: 1 1 33%;
}

.secondBlock{
  flex: 1 1 66%;
  display: flex;
}

.fullPrice{
  flex: 1 1 77%;
  font-size: 10em;
  font-weight:600;
  line-height: .8em;
}
.restPrice{
  flex: 1 1 33%;
}

.info{
  padding-top: .5em;
  font-size: 1.7em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapp">
  <div class="priceWrapp">
    <div class="firstBlock">
      <div>R$</div>
      <div>12x</div>
    </div>
        
    <div class="secondBlock">
      <div class="fullPrice">219</div>
      <div class="restPrice">,91</div>
    </div>
  </div>
        
  <div class="info">a vista R$ 2.638,90</div>        
</div>
```